# Get country code by country name javascript?

Tags: javascript, country-codes

Is there a way to get the country code (Alpha-2) from a country name in JavaScript?

Comment: Where are you getting the country name from? A normalized list of some sort?

Comment: Not by default, but you can build something yourself or use some kind of lookup service.

Comment: @AustinTFrench The purpose is that a user can input country in a form, when they submit that form the country input should result in a country code in the backend that is sent to another system to gather data.. im building a script for it and thought if there was a way to get this info without needing to create a custom function for it.

Comment: I don't think this is the same as the question that it's marked as a duplicate of.  It is asking to do the opposite -- to convert from a name to its code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this API https://restcountries.eu/

```
fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/kenya").then(resp=>{
      return resp.json();
}).then(json=>{
      console.log(json[0].alpha2Code);
})
```

Comment: `v2` API is not working anymore, here's the updated API link: `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/kenya`